# How to Get a maximum time i:e: dd-mm-yyy 23:59:59 from a given date?

Tags: sql

I want to get maximum time of a given date from a query that returns From and to Date:

1. A function named `[fn_COM_PeriodSplit]` returns output like

   ```
   Output:
   PrSeq   FromDate                 ToDate
   1       2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  2015-05-25 23:29:29.000

   PrSeq   FromDate                ToDate
   1       2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-05-07 00:00:00.000
   2       2015-05-08 00:00:00.000 2015-05-14 00:00:00.000
   3       2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 2015-05-21 00:00:00.000
   4       2015-05-22 00:00:00.000 2015-05-25 23:59:59.000
   ```
2. But I want the to date like

   ```
   PrSeq   FromDate                 ToDate
   1       2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  2015-05-25 23:59:59.000
   ```

How to get to date as maximum of end time?

Comment: What RDBMS? All the datetime functiosn are vendor specific.

Comment: ...or most dbms products aren't SQL standard compliant when it comes to date/time. (But some are ok.)